# Match, adding, and multiplication for polynomials using Linked List

Tags: c++, math, linked-list

So  i'm writing a program that consists of multiplication function implementations, however, i am having trouble writing 3 funtions: match, adding, and multipication.

The match function is supposed to tell whether 2 polynomials are the same. if so returns true, else false.

Add function jut adds 2 polynomials.

Multiplication just produces the product of 2 polynomials.

I am stuck on how to begin these functions. Any advice or feedback will be helpful. Thank you so much.

```
class Dlist
{
private:
Node* front;
public:
Dlist(Node* f = NULL){front = f;}

void insertInOrder(int c, int x, int y)
{
    Node* nn = new Node;
    nn->coef = c;
    nn->xdeg = x;
    nn->ydeg = y;
    int nsum = x + y;

    Node* p = front;


    if(front == NULL){
        front = nn;
        return;
    }
    while(p != NULL){
        if(x == p->xdeg && y == p->ydeg){
            p->coef += c;
            return;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    p = front;
    if(nsum > p->xdeg + p->ydeg){
        nn->next = p;
        front = nn;
        return;
    }
    else{
        while(p->next != NULL && p->next->xdeg + p->next->ydeg > nsum){
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
    nn->next = p->next;
    p->next = nn;
    return;
};

void print()
{
    Node* p = front;
    while(p != NULL){
        cout << p->coef << "/" << p->xdeg << "/" << p->ydeg << " -> ";
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "NULL" << endl;
    return;
};

int degree()
{
    Node* p = front;
    int maxd = 0;

    while(p != NULL){
        if(maxd < p->xdeg + p->ydeg){
            maxd = p->xdeg + p->ydeg;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }

    return maxd;
};

void coefficient(int input)
{
    Node* p = front;
   int index = 0;
   while(p != NULL){
        p = p->next;
        index++;
   }
   if(input < 0){
        cout << "Does not exist." << endl;
        return;
   }
   else if(input > index){
        cout << "Does not exist." << endl;
        return;
   }
   p = front;
   for(int i = 0; i != input; i++){
        p = p->next;
   }
   cout << p->coef << endl;
   return;
}
void sum()
{


}
```

};

Comment: Representing polynomials as 'std::vector' ease up things (Side note:  calculating with polynomials becomes inaccurate very soon )

Answer (score 0):

If we think about the psudocode for each algorithm you might have something like

```
function match(poly1,poly2):
    if(length(poly1) != length(poly2)) return false
    foreach term1 in poly1:
        boolean termmatched=false
        foreach term2 in poly2:
            if matchterms(term1,term2):
                termmatched = true
                break
        endfor
        if not termmatched:
            return false
    endfor
    return true
endfunction
```

So this search first checks you have the same number of term in each polynomial. Then for each term in the first polynomial check to see if there is any term in the second polynomial which matches. If no term matches then the polynomials don't match and we can return straight away.

This does assume that you can't have a term in the second polynomial which can match two different terms in the first. A more sophisticated approach might set a flag for each term on the second polynomial to check whether its already been matched.

For adding you want to find any terms which match and add the coefficients. If there is no match then just add that term. Here you probably want to use a flag to detect which terms in the second polynomial is matched. Alternatively you could removed matched terms from the second polynomial.

```
function add(poly1,poly2):
    boolean flags[length(poly2)] // array of flags all false
    polynomial result = empty polynomial
    foreach term1 in poly1:
        boolean termmatched=false
        int i=0
        foreach term2 in poly2:
            if matchterms(term1,term2):
                result.add(new term(term1.coef+term2.coef,term1.xdeg,term1.ydeg))
                flags[i]=true   // mark flag for second term as matched
                termmatched = true
                break
             ++i
        endfor
        if not termmatched:
            result.add(new term(term1.coef,term1.xdeg,term1.ydeg))
    endfor

    i =0
    foreach term2 in poly2:
        if( not flags[i]) 
            result.add(new term(term1.coef,term1.xdeg,term1.ydeg))
    endfor
endfunction
```

multiplication can be trickier. It depends a bit on your polynomial class. A good polynomial class will have an add method which will loop through all the existing terms to check for a match

```
class polynomial

methods add(coef,xord,yord):
    foreach term:
        if match(term,xord,yord):
            term.coef += coef
            return
    endfor
    // add a new term on the end of the linked list
    insertInOrder(coef,xord,yord)
```

with this method multiplication simply becomes

```
function multiply(poly1,poly2):
    result = new polynomial
    foreach term1 in poly1:
        foreach term2 in poly2:
            result.add( term1.coef*term2.coef,
                term1.xord + term2.xord,
                term1.yord + term2.yord)
        endfor
     endfor
     return result
 endfunction
```

With this smart add method the adding two polynomials now becomes trivial

```
function add(poly1,poly2):
    result = new polynomial
    foreach term1 in poly1:
        result.add(term1.coef,term1.xord,term1.yord)
    endfor
    foreach term2 in poly2:
        result.add(term2.coef,term2.xord,term2.yord)
    endfor
    return result
endfunction
```